# multiple join and set in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 13 tables which have the same structure:

```
id  switch_name area
```

each table contains different switch_name for a specific area. For example,

```
table1:
id    switch_name area
56    xxxx        A
77    yyyy        A
table2:
id    switch_name area
89    zzzz        B
78    uuuu        B
```

I need to use these tables to update another table "results" which contains the id and waits to be filled up with the area value.

So I would do this command:

```
UPDATE results JOIN table1 ON results.switch_id = table1.id SET results.area = table1.area
```

This works fine for one table, however I want to join all these 13 tables. Let's take two of them for example, can I write the query like this:

```
 UPDATE results JOIN table1 ON results.switch_id = table1.id JOIN table2 ON results.switch_id = table2.id SET results.area = table1.area, results.area = table2.area
```

or

```
UPDATE results JOIN table1 ON results.switch_id = table1.id SET results.area = table1.area JOIN table2 ON results.switch_id = table2.id SET results.area = table2.area
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the `tableN` tables have the same structure but different contents, `UNION ALL` them all together in a subquery and join against that.

```
UPDATE 
  results
  JOIN (
    SELECT id, switch_name, area FROM table1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT id, switch_name, area FROM table2
    UNION ALL
    ..
    ..
    SELECT id, switch_name, area FROM table13
  ) alltogether ON results.switch_id = alltogether.id
SET results.area = alltogether.area
WHERE <conditions for update>
```

In the long run, if those tables are all similar but holding different subsets of the same dataset, they should probably be combined into *one* table that has a column which differentiates their sources.

Use something like the following to merge them into a single table:

```
INSERT INTO new_combined_table 
  (id, switch_name, area, source)
  SELECT id, switch_name, area, 't1' AS source FROM table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, switch_name, area, 't2' AS source FROM table2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, switch_name, area, 't3' AS source FROM table3
  ..
  ..
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT id, switch_name, area, 't13' AS source FROM table13
```

Comment: THANKS!! Yes, you are right, I also want to merge them into one table, is there any query to do that? Or I should do it manually?